# Error parsing XML: Unbound pre-fix?

Tags: android, xml

I am getting the error in title when I try to implement the following XML code.

The specific line i get the error at it is:

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
```

How can I solve this?

Full Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStroopColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="  "
            android:textSize="60dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStroop1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="47dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStroop2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="47dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivStroopImageResults"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStroopScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvStroopResults"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="35dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStroopCountdown"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvStroopScore"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint=" "
            android:textSize="34dp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing this tag

< com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView

xmlns:circularimageview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your-packagename"

.....>

Answer (score 1):

When you use custom attributes for a view, you must specify its namespace at the root node tag. Try to do the following with your linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```